# Flask-sqlalchemy query datetime intervals

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have defined a table with flask-sqlalchemy. Displayed below.

```
class Notes(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    notes = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    added_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())

@staticmethod
def newest(num):
    return Notes.query.order_by(desc(Notes.added_at)).limit(num)
```

I'm attempting to write a query that is to replace and already existing direct query, which looks like this.

```
select notes,user,added_at from notes where added_at >= now() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR;
```

However based on the documentation that I can find, I'm not able to find a method to do the same. I'm able to make simpler queries, but I'm struggling to recreate what's pretty simple in sql itself.

I'm more than willing to read some documentation surrounding it, wasn't able to precisely nail that down either. Any direction you could provide would be awesome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy: how to filter date field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895208/sqlalchemy-how-to-filter-date-field)

Comment: I saw this, however it didn't quite have enough information to recreate the interval function I was trying to accomplish. Thank you though.

Comment: @nathancahill not a duplicate. The linked question is not using DB-internal "intervals"

Answer (score 18):

The following should also work:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import INTERVAL
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import concat

Notes.query\
    .filter(
        Notes.added_at >= (func.now() - func.cast(concat(8, ' HOURS'), INTERVAL))
    )\
    .limit(num)
```

It has the nice property that `8` can be replaced with a value from inside the database, e.g., if you joined in another table with dynamic intervals. I gave this answer also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267267/using-postgressql-interval-in-sqlalchemy-where-the-duration-is-dynamically-store/57267696#57267696).

Answer (score 15):

I always have Python's `datetime` library get me the "now" and "8 hours ago", then just do a filter using the datetimes:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
eight_hours_ago = now - timedelta(hours=8)

Notes.query.filter(Notes.added_at > eight_hours_ago).filter(Notes.added_at < now).all()
```

Comment: This could lead to subtle issues with time-zones. In addition, `now()` in the Python process will not be the same as `now()` on the postgres server (even without considering time-zones). If you have time-critical queries you *should* use the DB-internal timestamps (that is, use `NOW()` inside the SQL query).

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like

```
Notes.query.order_by(desc(Notes.added_at)).filter(
    Notes.added_at >= text('NOW() - INTERVAL 8 HOURS').limit(num)
```

As I only use pure sqlalchemy I tested this out with this syntax:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import text
>>> # s is a standard sqlalchemy session created from elsewhere.
>>> print s.query(Notes).order_by(desc(Notes.added_at)).filter(
...     Notes.added_at >= text('NOW() - INTERVAL 8 HOURS'))
SELECT notes.id AS notes_id, notes.notes AS notes_notes, notes.added_at AS notes_added_at 
FROM notes 
WHERE notes.added_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 8 HOURS ORDER BY notes.added_at DESC
```

Reason for using `text` for that section is simply because `NOW()` and `INTERVAL` usage is not consistent across all sql implementations (certain implementations require the use of `DATEADD` to do datetime arithmetic, and while sqlalchemy does support the `Interval` type it's not really well documented, and also on my brief testing with it it doesn't actually do what you needed (using example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573750/2904896), for both sqlite and MySQL).  If you intend to use the SQL backend as an ordered (but dumb) data store you can just construct the actual query from within Python, perhaps like so:

```
q = s.query(Notes).order_by(desc(Notes.added_at)).filter(
    Notes.added_at >= (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(3600 * 8))
)
```

Some people dislike this as some databases (like postgresql) can deal with datetime better than Python (such as timedelta is ignorant of leap years, for instance).

Comment: `text('NOW() - INTERVAL 8 HOURS')` doesn't work, you need quotas inside like this `text("NOW() - INTERVAL '8 HOURS'")`

Comment: @KonstantinSmolyanin It was a direct copy of the query OP wrote, I made it to generate the equivalent query they wanted.  Also the other answers are definitely better than this dated initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can also try

```
from sqlalchemy import func, text

@staticmethod
def newest(num):
    return Notes.query.filter(Notes.added_at >= (func.date_sub(func.now(),  text('INTERVAL  8 HOUR')).order_by(desc(Notes.added_at)).limit(num)
```

OR

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz 

@staticmethod
def newest(num):
    recent = datetime.now(tz=tz.tzlocal()) - timedelta(hours=8)

    return Notes.query.filter(Notes.added_at >= recent).order_by(desc(Notes.added_at)).limit(num)
```

Comment: date_sub is not a postgres function :(

Comment: Yeah it’s a MySQL function can use `NOW() - '8 HOUR'::INTERVAL` instead

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy automatically adapts Python `timedelta` instances to correct `interval` queries. To use them you will need to rewrite your query in such a way that either the left-hand-side or right-hand-side of the comparison operator is an interval. That way it becomes comparable with timedeltas.

You query currently reads like this:

```sql
WHERE added_at >= now() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```

On both sides of the comparator `>=` you have absolute timestamps. And this is difficult to translate to SQLAlchemy. You can rewrite it like this:

```sql
WHERE now() - added_at >= INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```

This gives you intervals on both sides. This is now pretty easy to translate to SQLAlchemy:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from sqlalchemy import func

class Notes(db.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def newest(num):
        query = Notes.query.filter(
            func.now() - Notes.added_at >= timedelta(hours=8)
        )
        return query.order_by(desc(Notes.added_at)).limit(num)
```

Compared to the existing answers, this...

- ... ensures that you use DB-internal timestamps (as opposed to using `datetime.now()` from Python)
- ... does not require any type-casting
- ... does not use string-concatenations
- ... does not use raw `text()`