# How can I select all items from the DB on a week period usign SQLALCHEMY (Flask)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I was wondering if there is a way to get a week or month period from DB. I have in my DB a `value` and a `date` and I want to get all items that their date are between for example `2020-03-01` and `2020-04-01`.

I tried the following code but it gives a warning and doesn't return nothing:

The code:

```
users_count = StatsUsers.query.filter(and_(func.date(StatsUsers.created_date >= '2020-03-30'), func.date(StatsUsers.created_date <= '2020-04-30')))
        for x in users_count:
            print(x.value)
        return render_template('admin/index.html', users_count=0)
```

The warning that it gives:

```
Warning: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '1'")
```

My DB:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue after reading this post:
[Flask-sqlalchemy query datetime intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495935/flask-sqlalchemy-query-datetime-intervals)

What I did was basically change the `filter(and_(func.date()))` to only `filter()` and making sure the DB was in `DATETIME`.

The new code:

```
users_count = StatsUsers.query.filter(StatsUsers.created_date >= '2020-03-01 00:00:00').filter(StatsUsers.created_date <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00').all()
        for x in users_count:
            print(x.value)
```