# SQALCHEMY query between two dates

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I looked at that link

It's weird because the query im doing is hit and miss.
It can't show the dates if the difference is only a few days

[SQLAlchemy: how to filter date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895208/sqlalchemy-how-to-filter-date-field)

model:

```
class UserCallsModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    date = db.Column(db.String(90))
    username = db.Column(db.String(90))
    event_name = db.Column(db.String(90))
```

query:

```
users = UserCallsModel.query.filter(UserCallsModel.date.between("2016-1-1",  "2016-1-20")).order_by(UserCallsModel.date.desc())
```

I've got 2 dates that fall within this range but is not getting queried?

Comment: Is there a time component to your dates in range? Dates default to `00:00:00`

Comment: Is your date field actually a string? If so, the database may not be properly comparing dates, but instead comparing them as strings. For example, '2016-01-05' is not "between" the two "dates" you have specified, neither is '2016-1-6'.

Comment: @MarkHildreth
so I 'll have to use a datetime object I guess it's my data types that were wrong? I was under the impression it'll actually be able to parse it because of the link in the post

Comment: @HoneyBadger I need that don't I?

Comment: With time component you can get edge effects, for example, should `2016-1-20 12:00:00` be included?

Comment: ok I don't have that.

but @MarkHildreth is right my dates are strings so I guess that whats making it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MySQL, but I imagine it is the same as PG which I've included output below.

When you use the "between" method, you end up using the "BETWEEN" operator, like so...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-1-1' AND '2016-1-20'
```

The problem is that the "between" operator does something different for dates versus strings. For example, if the value that it is testing is a string, it will see the arguments (the `'2016-1-1' AND '2016-1-20'` part) as strings.

```
mhildreth=# select '2016-1-5' between '2016-1-1' AND '2016-1-10';
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Meanwhile, if the value that it is testing is a date object, then it will implicitly convert the strings to date objects, essentially doing the following...

```
mhildreth=# select '2016-1-5'::date between '2016-1-1'::date AND '2016-1-10'::date;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Thus, my guess is that you want to convert your "date" column to be a date type. If you must leave it a string, then you need to ensure that you are using a date format that also works when doing string comparison. Thus, you'll need `2016-01-01` rather than `2016-1-1`.

Comment: The converting the date to a date object is write I got it to work now.

however formatting the string to be `yyyy-mm-dd` instead of `yyyy-m-d` might be the reason why the dates were off. I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that a string will actually be queried correctly as long as it was of a certain format. but nope I'm afraid it ain't so.

a better way of doing this if you have strings formatted like this:
`"2016-1-5"` is to simply convert the string date  to a datetime.date object

python 3

```
import datetime
splitted_date  = [int(number) for number in "2016-1-5".split("-")]
formatted_date = datetime.date(*splitted_date)
```

Comment: This is cute but I think `formatted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-1-5", "%Y-%m-%d")` is a better way to ingest a date string because it is explicit about which is the month. (Is 2016-1-5 Jan-5th or May-1st ?)