# BETWEEN clause in SQLAlchemy with seleted columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to execute this query in SQLAlchemy

```
SELECT customer_name FROM Orders
WHERE order_id = 101 AND order_date BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-31';
```

here is my Model:

```
class Orders(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    customer_name = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    order_date = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    remarks = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
```

Comment: What issues are you having that prevent you from doing that? Have you read for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895208/sqlalchemy-how-to-filter-date-field?

Comment: @IljaEverilä: thanks for that link, I've duplicated the post to there.

Comment: sorry, i also want selected values in where clause. 
how can i execute this, SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderID = 10248 AND OrderDate BETWEEN #01/07/1996# AND #31/07/1996#; in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: i have read this but my problem is little bit different.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just call the [`column.between()` method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.ColumnProperty.Comparator.between), and pass in both dates (strings here, since you defined the column with `db.String(100)`). Pass the result of the call to the `Query.filter()` method.

Assuming you are using the Flask SQLAlchemy model as base:

```
Orders.query.filter(Orders.order_date.between('2018-07-01', '2018-07-31'))
```

As long as you use ISO8601 formatted strings as dates this'll work, but it'd be better if you used `db.Date()` as the column type, and then use Python's `datetime.date()` objects to do the comparison.

Comment: how can i  execute this,
 SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE OrderID = 10248 AND OrderDate BETWEEN #01/07/1996# AND #31/07/1996#;
in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @HamzaAwan: this is getting to be rather basic; just add another `filter()` to the query for the order id.

Comment: Orders.query.filter(Orders.order_date.between('2018-07-01', '2018-07-31')).filter(orde_id = 101), you mean like this?

Comment: @HamzaAwan: `.filter()` takes clauses built by column expressions such as `Orders.order_id == 101`. You can use `.filter_by()` which takes column names as keyword arguments, so `Orders.query.filter(Orders.order_date.between('2018-07-01', '2018-07-31')).filter?by(order_id=101)` works too. `filter_by()` is limited to equality clauses.

Comment: @HamzaAwan: see the [*Querying* section of the SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying), highly recommended reading!

Comment: thanks Martin it's working.