# PostgreSQL SQL Alchemy AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'between'

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have an ORM query as follows

```
results = db.session.query(MyData).filter(MyData.last_updated_date_time.between(from_date, to_date)).all()
```

passing parameters for from date is `2020-12-14 04:00:00` and for to date is `2020-12-15 04:00:00`
and `last_updated_date_time` holds values
`2020-12-09 03:08:22.301+00` , `2020-12-14 01:26:30.737+00`
all are valid date time objects

This query works fine for some occasions and throws error stating

```
MyData.last_updated_date_time.between(from_date, to_date)
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'between'
ERROR:root:Error creating query 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'between'
```

What can be the issue for this error?

Comment: It's been awhile since I used SqlAlchemy, but shouldn't that be:`filter(between(MyData.last_updated_date_time, from_date, to_date))`?

Comment: hi @AdrianKlaver can use between for datetime column as per the code

Comment: Then somewhere `MyData.last_updated_date_time` is not the `Column last_updated_date_time` but the value of `last_updated_date_time`. This from the error message `'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'between'`. You are trying to run `between` on a `datetime` not a `Column`.  We will have to see what happens before the above to get a better answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Its referring to the column and I have followed the following 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53158540/1004875

Comment: The error says it is not. You need to resolve that. We can help if you show the code that leads up the query you posted.