# How to filter SQLAlchemy objects with datefield values before today?

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I wish to keep all objects from the database which have a particular datetime field with values before the current day. I can see how you an filter with [hardcoded dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898533/14649310) or [between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69267747/14649310), but how can I keep all items with dates before today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems it is quite straight forward you can do direct datetime comparison in `SQLAlchemy` queries like this:

```
    q = DBSession.query(User).filter(
        User.sign_up_date <= datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    )
```

which would return all `user` objects which signed up one hour ago.